# Android list view to another details view

Tags: java, android, string, listview

I am developing an android application... The first page has a list view where different cities names are there.. i know when the user clicks the single list item it will go to a page and display the content.. But my need is when the user clicks on each single item in list view ..it has to go to different pages .. the detail page of cities... if there is 10 list items is there ..when user click on each list item ... different page has to come... ffor example different cities like new york, London, sydeny..etc.. when user presses london button ...it has to go to london page description

```
public class SingleListItem extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item_view);

        TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        String product = i.getStringExtra("product");

        txtProduct.setText(product);
}
}
```

in this when user press on single list it will go to its product page...

```
public class AndroidListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);


        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, adobe_products));

        ListView lv = getListView();


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
              int position, long id) {


              String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();


              Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);

              i.putExtra("product", product);
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see your problem here, you have several possibilites:

1. You can identify your new intents with your position using a `switch`. In case 0, you jump to New York, in case 1, you jump London etc.

   switch(position){

   ```
   case 0:
   //call intent NewYork
   break;
   case 1:
   ...
   ```

   }
2. If you have tons of list items this could trasnform your code into a spaghetti. In this case I would create an ArrayList with the cities insde it in the suitable sequence. So if position 0 directs you to the NewYorkListItem.class, you write this String into the 0th position of your ArrayList etc.. You can easily call a class like:
   `Class.forName("com.example."+mArrayList.get(position) + "ListItem");` where the 0th position in your mArrayList contains "NewYork".
3. If you dont use activites the Fragment solution is another nice way I think. But this way you have to add the fragments via `FragmentTransaction` since you can only replace the fragments which you added dynamically with the transaction.

Hope this helps!